# ffmpeg: How do I loop audio when encoding video?

Tags: video, loops, audio, ffmpeg, encode

I'm trying to encode a video with an mp3 and have that audio stream loop while the video stream is still running. The video steam is priority.

I haven't seen commands in ffmpeg that allow this specifically. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Duplicate question :

Adding repeated background audio with ffmpeg


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930296/adding-repeated-background-audio-with-ffmpeg#8017021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ffmpeg supports this functionality.  As far as I know, you will have to generate your audio loop in a new mp3 file outside of ffmpeg prior to overlaying the audio on your video.