# Adding background music using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I've been trying to add background audio to another audio file. Here is what I tried :

```
      const audio_urls = ['/path/audio1.m4a', '/path/audio2.m4a'];
      const file_name = 'merged_file.m4a';
      ffmpeg()
      .input(audio_urls[0])
      .input(audio_urls[1])
      .on('end', async function (output) {
        console.log(output, 'files have been merged and saved.')
      })
      .saveToFile(file_name)
```

For some reason the file generated only has the second audio file sound (i.e. audio2.m4a). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a complex filter to create a downmix of 2 audio inputs

`fluent-ffmpeg` doesn't mention anything about "overlaying" 2 inputs, I guess your best chance is to use a complex filter and create a down mix of the 2 audio samples.

You can either use the `amix` filter, which mixes multiple audio inputs into a single output, or the `amerge` filter, which merges two or more audio streams into a single multi-channel stream. I suggest you use the `amix` filter.

**How to use complex filter with `fluent-ffmpeg`:**

```js
ffmpeg()
      .input(audio_urls[0])
      .input(audio_urls[1])
      .complexFilter([
        {
           filter : 'amix', options: { inputs : 2, duration : 'longest' }
        }
      ])
      .on('end', async function (output) {
        console.log(output, 'files have been merged and saved.')
      })
      .saveToFile(file_name)
```

A more detailed answer about the filter specifically : [How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-downmix-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)

The docs about complexFilter() : https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#complexfilterfilters-map-set-complex-filtergraph

Comment: Thanks @Pascal Lamers. That worked. Another thing I wanted to add was to loop the first audio as it gets mixed with second audio file. Now the filter mixes the first audio just once. I tried another filter called 'aloop' and I changed the complex filter accordingly as ```   .complexFilter([
        {
          filter : 'aloop', options: { loop : -1}
        },
        {
           filter : 'amix', options: { inputs : 2, duration : 'longest' }
        }
      ])```. But that results in the following error "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_amix_1".

Comment: I looked for a solution, but didn't find anything useful. Could be that your operation would need 2 steps, first looping, then mixing. Maybe this answer helps you with the loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930296/adding-repeated-background-audio-with-ffmpeg

Comment: It's better to first find a solution using plain ffmpeg commands and then translate it into fluent-ffmpeg code