# FFMpeg Add Background Music to Video

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I wanna add a background music on my video.
I tried this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio.m4a -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -ac 2 output.mkv
```

It worked but when music ended, My Video Sound end too.
I want to repeate the background music until video end.
And if I can change background music volume it will be awosome

Comment: can it help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930296/adding-repeated-background-audio-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and wanna share it with you guys

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.08[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -shortest output.mp4
```

It make the audio looped and play it until video end with audio volume 0.08 and you can change it here

Comment: this query is working correctly as per my need, however as per my use case I need to give option to remove the audio, can you help me to get the query to remove the track?